# colocar a la derecha la imagen

Tags: css, css3

Buenas! ¿Como puedo hacer para que la segunda imagen este a la derecha?

Le puse una clase sola para ella que se llama `derecha` pero el problema que al darle float right, la página pierde su flujo y se amontonan unas sobre otras.

Simplemente quiero que la segunda, la imagen este al otro lado, es decir primero fondo rojo y a su derecha la imagen.

Saludos.

```css
/*********************************************** PROYECTOS ************************/

.General-Proyectos {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.Proyectos {
  height: 800px;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: auto;
}

.Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos {
  height: 206px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #b00000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.Imagenes-Proyectos img {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #b00000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.Imagenes-Proyectos img:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.Derecha {
  /* ????????????????????????? */
}
```

```html
<div class="General General-Proyectos">
  <div class="Proyectos">
    <h2>Mis proyectos</h2>

    <div class="Imagenes-Proyectos">
      <div class="Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos">
        <img src="Img/inLaw.png" alt="inLaw Proyecto">
      </div>
      <div class="Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos Derecha">
        <img src="Img/inLaw.png" alt="inLaw Proyecto">
      </div>
      <div class="Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos">
        <img src="Img/inLaw.png" alt="inLaw Proyecto">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la imagen a la derecha del fondo, pero sobre el fondo o fuera del fondo? es decir, lo quieres como en la captura?

Comment: @GDP Lo quiero como en la captura pero con la de en medio en el lado derecho. Es decir sobre el fondo, pero a la derecha.

Comment: Mira la respuesta que te he dado entonces, creo que es la que te vale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes alinearla por css con la propiedad [text-align](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

```
text-align: right;
```

---

***OBSOLETO***-> O en HTML con la propiedad [align](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_img_align)

```
align="right"
```

```css
.General-Proyectos {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.Proyectos {
  height: 800px;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: auto;
}

.Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos {
  height: 206px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #b00000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.Imagenes-Proyectos img {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #b00000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.Imagenes-Proyectos img:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.Derecha {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="General General-Proyectos">
  <div class="Proyectos">
    <h2>Mis proyectos</h2>

    <div class="Imagenes-Proyectos">
      <div class="Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos">
        <img src="http://www.focolare.org/usa/files/2013/05/Law.jpg" alt="inLaw Proyecto" align="right">
      </div>
      <div class="Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos Derecha">
        <img src="http://www.focolare.org/usa/files/2013/05/Law.jpg" alt="inLaw Proyecto Derecha">
      </div>
      <div class="Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos">
        <img src="http://www.focolare.org/usa/files/2013/05/Law.jpg" alt="inLaw Proyecto" align="right">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, no uses [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com) como referencia... porque te enseñan ejemplos con códigos obsoletos: [align](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-img-align)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner una fila `row` por cada fila que quieras realizar.

```css
/*********************************************** PROYECTOS ************************/

.General-Proyectos {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.Proyectos {
  height: 800px;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: auto;
}

.Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos {
  height: 206px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #b00000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.Imagenes-Proyectos img {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #b00000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.Imagenes-Proyectos img:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.Derecha {
  /* ????????????????????????? */
}

.row {
display:inline-table;
}
```

```html
<div class="General General-Proyectos">
  <div class="Proyectos">
    <h2>Mis proyectos</h2>

    <div class="Imagenes-Proyectos">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos">
        <img src="Img/inLaw.png" alt="inLaw Proyecto">
      </div>
      <div class="Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos Derecha">
        <img src="Img/inLaw.png" alt="inLaw Proyecto">
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="Individual-Imagenes-Proyectos">
        <img src="Img/inLaw.png" alt="inLaw Proyecto">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```